# get a data-attribute (data-phone) value from the selected datalist option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

how to get a data-attribute (like:- data-phone ) value from the selected datalist option which is selected;
It send me just value not data attribute.

**i want to set data-phone of input from data-phone of datalist > option**

How can I set this? **Help**

**Html:**

```
     <input type="text" name="patirnt_name" id="patirnt_name" list="patient_list" onfocus="getAllPatients()" value="" data-phone="">
         <datalist id="patient_list">

         </datalist>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function getAllPatients() {
            let url = "{{ route('get-all-patient-ajax') }}";
            let list = $('#patient_list');

            let html = '';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(res) {
                    let data = res.patients;

                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        html +=
                            `<option value="${value.F_name}" data-phone="${value.phone}" >${value.F_name}</option >`;
                    });

                    list.html(html);

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: And this is not working `data-phone="${value.phone}"`?  Are you sure you have `value.phone`

Comment: yeah . i have use this many time

Comment: this value.phone is return correct value. but I can't transfer this value to the data-phone of attribute of input.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, when you `list.html(html)` all the options are displayed in the DOM without the `data-phone="${value.phone}"` that you set in the `each` loop. You could try this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('<option/>', { 
          value : value.F_name,
          data-phone : value.phone
    }).text(value.F_name).appendTo(list);
});
```

Comment: doesn't work this

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work this"?